# Как конвертировать строку в list?

Tags: python, парсер, list, текст

Я хочу конвертировать это:

```
"21:14:23"
```

В это:

```
[21, 14, 23]
```

Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 9):

[python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x)

```
print "21:14:23".split(":")
# ['21', '14', '23']
print map(int, "21:14:23".split(":"))
# [21, 14, 23]
import re
print re.split('[:;.@]', "21:14@23", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
# ['21', '14', '23']
```

Answer (score 5):

?

```
= list(map(int, string.split(':')))
```

Answer (score 5):

Другой вариант через регулярку:

```
import re

items = re.findall(r'\d+', "21:14:23")
print(items)  # ['21', '14', '23']

items = [int(i) for i in items]
print(items)  # [21, 14, 23]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "21:14:23"
print(s.rsplit(":")) #['21', '14', '23']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line = "21:14:23"

a = list(map(int, line.split(":")) # [21, 14, 23])
```

каждое число в массиве в формате `int`

Comment: `print(a) # <map object at 0x7fab2e2db190>`. Если добавить list, то получится вот этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/892160/1365 . Ну или если вы используете python2, то вариант `print map(int, "21:14:23".split(":"))` уже есть в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/892159/1365

Comment: insolor, теперь все нормально

Comment: Технически да, но теперь это фактически дубль другого ответа.